# Error android:layout_marginEnd with appcompat v7 library

Tags: eclipse, adt, android-5.0-lollipop, android-lint, android-appcompat

I got this error:

```
removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <ImageView>
```

from the `abc_activity_chooser_view.xml` XML file when compiling the `appcompat v7 library` in my Android project.

Things I have tried:

1. Uninstall Eclipse Luna and Android SDK completely.
2. Re-install Eclipse Luna and Android SDK.
3. Install the require Android components via Android SDK Manager.
4. In Eclipse, ask Android Lint to ignore the error in Preferences and **Skip Library Project Dependencies**.
5. Clean and build all projects.
6. Add `-clean` directive to `eclipse.ini` file.

But without any success.

Tools I used are:

- OS: Window 7 64-bit
- IDE: Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (v4.4.2) Build 20150219-0600
  64-bit
- Android SDK: Android v5.1.1 (API Level 22)
- ADT: v23.0.6.1720515
- Android SDK Tools: v24.1.2
- Android SDK Platform Tools: v22
- Android SDK Build Tools: v22.0.1
- Android Support Repository: v12
- Android Support Library: v22

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to fix, or workaround this error till Google fix this error?

I can't deploy my Android package until this error is fixed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It looks like Google will need to release an updated version of ADT to fix this issue.

Comment: @CKDPublishing: I found a solution- see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the `android:layout_marginEnd` error, within Eclipse, open the `project.properties` file within the `appcompat` v7 library and add the following directives:

```
target=android-21
sdk.buildtools=21.1.2
```

Note: You may need to install the Android SDK Build Tools v21.1.2 [if you haven't already] via the Android SDK Manager.

For those wishing to support Android 5.1+ (API 22) in your Android apps, you can add the following directives to the `project.properties` file of each of your Android project:

```
target=android-22
sdk.buildtools=22.0.1
```

Note: You may need to install the Android SDK Build Tools v22.0.1 [if you haven't already] via the Android SDK Manager.

So, in essence, you're using one version of the Android SDK Build Tools to build your Android apps, and another to fix the `android:layout_marginEnd` error in the `appcompat` v7 library.

The documentation for the `sdk.buildtools` directive is [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html). The documentation also include info on how to setup the `buildToolsVersion` directive in the `build.gradle` file for those using Android Studio and Gradle.